# AngularFirestore returns incorrect data

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a strange problem with AngularFire2
So there is a component constructor (i have correctly initialized firebase)

```
constructor(private store: AngularFirestore) {
    store.collection("users")
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe(next => {
            console.dir(next);
        });
}
```

And in response i have an empty result `Array(0)`.
But there are two documents. Why? I have no idea

[image]

**EDIT**
i have created another collection. And that worked
Something strange actually
So this is because of custom names for documents
Got it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data is loaded from the cache.

You can check this by subscribing to snapshot changes and look at the metadata:

```
snapshot.metadata.fromCache
```

In AngularFire2 caching is enabled by importing `AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()` to your current angular module.

See:

- [Tutorial about how to enable offline data in AngularFire2](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-with-angularfire-basics/#Offline-Data)
- [Firestore documentation about offline data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)

Comment: This works! I copied `enablePersistence()` from an example and got cached data as well. Removing this solved it. I was testing database rules with different Google logins and got cached data that some users should not supposed to see.